# How to show icon but hide notification in taskbar?

Tags: windows, taskbar, icons, notification-area

How to show icon but hide notification of a specific application in taskbar?

[image]

Comment: Does the software(ManicTime Tracker) have an option to disable notifications?

Comment: unfortunately, no